# Data integrity/operation performance optimization in relational databases

Tags: design, database

Recently come across an unusual scenario while normalizing an old relational database.

**The Facts**

There's ~8 tables linked to a central table, where references between the numerous tables *may or may not* exist.

There's a lot of data used, and while this table was initially designed, created and mutated over time, performance was taken into account. Thus, there were no linking tables made between the central & other tables.

I'm looking to improve the structure of this, but not sacrifice query performance, since information from all of the tables can be used for reporting.

**Question:**
How would one go about optimizing/normalizing a table structure like the one mentioned, without sacrificing the performance factor?

I've considered the following options:

**1**: Adding linking tables between them would make queries quite advanced, where if a lookup is done, all of the pivot tables would need to be searched to identify any relations between them.

**2**: Adding the central table id as an index on the outer tables. This is an idea, but then again, to find any information, you'd need to query the other tables. To maybe improve on this, adding a type field of some kind on the central table entry would assist to identify the information that exists on the outer tables.

**Edit - ERD Example**

[image]

As an example, consider a computer repair store. For the purposes of the example, the following assumptions are made:

- This is a small sub-system, a customer could have come in to buy an RGB fan, and didn't bring a device in. Thus, Customers don't have to have a CustomerDevice
- When a Repair is done, and a RepairActivity is recorded, the customer could bring it back in because of whatever reason.
- For every RepairActivity, a 1 to 1 relationship can be seen between the WorkInformation table.
- A RepairInvoice is only generated when the customer comes into the store, thus, a RepairActivity can exist without one.
- A Customer may have a CustomerDevice registered on the system, and not have brought it in for a repair.

Now this is a basic example, and the system mentioned in the question has many more tables attached.

Comment: What you call "linking tables" are only necessary when the relationship is M:N. 1:M relationships don't need such an intermediate table. Also, could you add an ER diagram, however crude, in order to better visualize the current design? No need to show columns, just tables and relationships. Sometimes "other tables", "central tables", "outer tables", is vague enough to hinder proper understading.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "improve the structure"?  It sounds like the app is working and doesn't have performance problems.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova I added an ERD example with a few tables for your understanding

Comment: @DanPichelman The app is being rewritten to account for a wider 'audiience' of customers if you will, and thus the database needs to be looked at. Came across some tables & we're thinking of updating them, the main issue being this table that is linked to a sparse variety of others

Comment: What does "WorkInformation" hold? It s a log?

Comment: @TulainsCórdova for the sake of this discussion, yea sure.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova was just an abstract table to further showcase the idea of my main question, doesn't really matter what it holds - point being, it's another table referenced by the central RepairActivity table

Comment: Yes, knowing what a table holds helps in the design process and/or identify design problems.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova ok cool, well say it does hold information pertaining to the work done. Comments from computer repair technicians, etc.

Comment: @N15M0_jk in a identity management software,pretty much every table is linked to a user (which means... really a lot), either directly, or indrectly (by a table which herself is linked to the user). I see nothing shocking here. However if you use some ORM tools to fetch your data, be prudent that you don't generate extra unnecessary requests. You may want to show us how you map your data in your application. This can be a problem even if the tables are fine by thersevles.

Answer (score 1):

Great first question and welcome.

**Short answer:**

Make shure every tables has a PK, that theres is a FK for every relationship and to add indexes on columns that will be queried often, and create views that abstract you from the joins if you don't want to said joins every time. Performance will be good. RDBMS are optimized to do exactly that.

**Long answer including some observations bases on limited information:**

1. `WORK_INFORMATION` and `REPAIR_ACTIVITY` having a 1:1 relationship, they have a high change of being the same entity. One possible exceptions is if `WORK_INFORMATION` has columns that do not apply to all `REPAIR_ACTIVITY`s, but, given the relationship is 1:1, I would considered whether or not they should be two separate tables. Also, 1:1 relationships are possible conceptually but not physically since you cannot insert in either table until a matching wor exists in the other... unless you are enforcing the integrity fully in code and not using database constraints.
2. *"Adding the central table id as an index on the outer tables."* First, I will assume that what you call *"central table"* is `REPAIR_ACTIVITY`. Well,those tables that have a relationship with `REPAIR_ACTIVITY` where `REPAIR_ACTIVITY` is on the one side of the relationship, should already have the PK of `REPAIR_ACTIVITY` as a column, i.e. a foreign key pointing to `REPAIR_ACTIVITY`, and all FKs are indexed. The tables that have a relationship with `REPAIR_ACTIVITY` where `REPAIR_ACTIVITY` is on the many side of the relationship shouldn't have a column with the `REPAIR_ACTIVITY` id. That would be physically impossible since there can be only one value on any row in the one side, making the relationship 1:1.
3. I would check the relationship between `REPAIR_INVOICE` and `REPAIR_ACTIVITY`. Is the relationship inverted (meaning `REPAIR_INVOICE` should be the one and `REPAIR_ACTIVITY` the many)? If not, disregard this suggestion and chalk it out to lack of information.
4. *"...adding a type field of some kind on the central table entry would assist to identify the information that exists on the outer tables"* That is in some cases unnecessary and in other cases impossible, **if what worries you is complexity of queries** do this: create views where you already join the tables. Then in your code you query those views. Thay way you will not have to write the joins every time, just the `WHERE` part to filter the selection.
5. **Regarding performance**, adding join tables where they are needed, shouldn't harm performance if all tables have a PK, there is a FK for every relationship and there are indexes on those columnes that will be queried often (PKs and FKs already have indexes).